# How to Add Multi-filter on Search Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

So I have made a simple search bar which is working fine, **but I'm lost on adding 2 filters (schoolyear 'sy') and (semester 'sem') using drop down.**
If user selects a specific schoolyear or semester the search would only display data containing the specific schoolyear and semester.

```
$allschedule = DB::table('load_schedule')
        ->leftjoin('emp_info', 'load_schedule.faculty_id', '=','emp_info.user_id')
        
        ->orderBy('lastname', 'ASC')
        ->orWhere('section', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('room', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('firstname', 'like', $src)
        ->select('load_schedule.*', 'emp_info.firstname', 'emp_info.lastname')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap all the `orWhere` statments together inside `where`

```
$allschedule = DB::table('load_schedule')
        ->leftjoin('emp_info', 'load_schedule.faculty_id', '=', 'emp_info.user_id')
            ->orderBy('lastname', 'ASC')
        ->where(function($query) use ($src){
        return $query->orWhere('section', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('room', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('firstname', 'like', $src);
        })
        ->select('load_schedule.*', 'emp_info.firstname', 'emp_info.lastname')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try a functional where your query for example

```
     $allschedule = DB::table('load_schedule')
    ->leftjoin('emp_info', 'load_schedule.faculty_id', '=','emp_info.user_id')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($src, $selection) {
         if ($src) {
             $query->orWhere('section', 'like', $src)
                ->orWhere('room', 'like', $src)
                ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', $src)
                ->orWhere('firstname', 'like', $src);
         }
         if ($selection === 'sy') {
             $query->where('schoolyear ', 'sy')
         }
         if ($selection === 'sem') {
             $query->where('schoolyear ', 'sem')
         }
     })
    ->orderBy('lastname', 'ASC')
    ->select('load_schedule.*', 'emp_info.firstname', 'emp_info.lastname')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Alternatively you could try :

```
$allschedule = DB::table('load_schedule')
        ->leftjoin('emp_info', 'load_schedule.faculty_id', '=','emp_info.user_id')            ->orderBy('lastname', 'ASC')
        ->orWhere('section', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('room', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', $src)
        ->orWhere('firstname', 'like', $src)
        ->select('load_schedule.*', 'emp_info.firstname', 'emp_info.lastname');

        if ($selection === 'sy') {
           $allschedule ->where('schoolyear ', 'sy')
        }
        if ($selection === 'sem') {
           $allschedule ->where('schoolyear ', 'sem')
        }

        return $allschedule->paginate(10);
```

also if your doing a search dont forget to add wild cards to your :D

```
where('firstName', 'like', '%' . $scr . '%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but somehow i could not make it work.

Comment: Thisif ($selection->sy) {
             $query->where('schoolyear ', 'sy')
         }

Comment: Attempt to read property "sy" on string

Comment: so what you could do is replace $selection->sy with $selecyion assuming $selection is "sy" | "sem" then your if statement will will check if  $selection === "sy"..  pls check edits

Comment: $selection='%'.$this->sy.'%';  do I still need this part??

Comment: Since my School Year dropdown and Sem are separate...

Comment: $selection='%'.$this->sy.'%' => this just for your search dont use it on your drop down, your dropdown you want to do exact matches but if you want to search you need to apply the % wildcards so that your search shows the correct items (so basically your firstname, lastname, section and room

Comment: So, in my drop the 'sy' value is passed to wire:model="filterSY"

Comment: So should i call this way  if ($selection) 
    {
    $query->where('schoolyear ', 'filterSy')
   
    }

Comment: yes that should work too

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, maybe its just who could not make this thing work. but thanks for the time and effort already upvoted and checked your answer